# Weird message about Wireless keyboard very low in power when changing to tablet mode (Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Inspiron 7306 2-in-1)

Tags: 20.04, dell, touchscreen, inspiron

I have a laptop Dell Inspiron 7306 2-in-1 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. When I convert the laptop to tablet mode and try to use the software keyboard in the touchscreen, Ubuntu sends a notification to the screen saying: Wireless keyboard is very low in power (1%). This device will soon stop functioning if not charged. And suddenly the touch screen just stops responding to user interaction and I have to go back to laptop mode turning back the keyboard to the front.

On a similar scenario: The laptop comes with a smart pen. When I try to use it without going into tablet mode, the touchscreen does respond to the pen input, but the message about the wireless keyboard with very low power (1%) persists. Also, in Settings->Power->Devices I have the Pen, at 100% and a device called CUST0000:00 04F3:2A2F at 1%, that I supossed is related to the problem.

Additional information: Ubuntu 20.04 Linux kernel 5.8.0-38-generic 64bits